# ImportError: cannot import name 'distribute_covar_matrix_to_match_covariance_type'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda, hmmlearn

I'm trying to run the code in the [hmmlearn tutorial](https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) but I get an import error from the removed method 'distribute_covar_matrix_to_match_covariance_type'.
I don't know how to install a version of hmmlearn in Anaconda that does not cause this problem.

I'm running this on Windows 10 with:

- (Name, Version, Build, Channel)
- hmmlearn, 0.3.0b, np112py36_0, omnia
- scikit-learn, 0.20.1, py36hb854c30_0
- python, 3.6.8, h9f7ef89_7

I have installed hmmlearn and scikit-learn though Anaconda with this command: `conda install -c omnia hmmlearn`.

It seems to me as tho the hmmlearn that is installed via Anaconda is not the latest version of hmmlearn because in the file `hmm.py` this line exist `from sklearn.mixture import (
    distribute_covar_matrix_to_match_covariance_type, _validate_covars
)`. [Compared the the latest version of hmmlearn](https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn/blob/0ec079ea8d3466132c8646aefe4f684aae748456/lib/hmmlearn/hmm.py#L15-L21)

In the bundeled scikit-learn that is installed with hmmlearn in Anaconda the`distribute_covar_matrix_to_match_covariance_type` method is removed, as it should be in scikit-learn 0.20.1. ([It was removed in 0.20](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/8c439fbe8c340389d7f9d99884180b2e7b21a79f/sklearn/mixture/gmm.py#L784-L785) )

```
from hmmlearn import hmm
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-16c29f744bfe> in <module>
----> 1 from hmmlearn import hmm

~\Documents\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\hmmlearn\hmm.py in <module>
     14 from scipy.misc import logsumexp
     15 from sklearn import cluster
---> 16 from sklearn.mixture import (
     17     distribute_covar_matrix_to_match_covariance_type, _validate_covars
     18 )

ImportError: cannot import name 'distribute_covar_matrix_to_match_covariance_type'
```

The problem seems to be that Anaconda is installing incompatible versions of hmmlearn and scikit-learn. Any suggestions on how I can install compatible versions of these packages?

Comment: The latest version according to docs and pypi seems to be 0.2.1. I am not sure what the version 0.3.0b is about. `omnia` seems to be a custom channel. You should always first try to install from official anaconda channels. If not available, go for `conda-forge`. The hmmlearn version available in conda-forge is 0.2.1.  https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/hmmlearn

Comment: Thank you @VivekKumar. It worked after I installed it via conda-forge with the command `conda install -c conda-forge hmmlearn`

Answer (score 0):

From @Vivek Kumar run
`conda install -c conda-forge hmmlearn`

If that doesn't work remove hmmlearn with

`conda remove hmmlearn`

then reinstall with pip

`pip install --upgrade --user hmmlearn`